# Appending a dynamic href and target to an anchor using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a piece of jQuery that allows me to have an 'image box' gallery, where if someone clicks on a thumb, the corresponding image gets loaded into the 'image box' div.

I've modified the code a little so that when a thumb gets clicked, it also loads in an anchor with the image's src, so that a user can open the image in a new tab.

My problem is that whenever I add target="_blank" to the anchor, the href doesn't get pulled in. Is there any way to add target="_blank" to the following code, without cancelling out the dynamic href ?

Thanks in advance !

```
jQuery(".gallery-item a").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    jQuery("#imageBox").append(
        jQuery("<img>", { src: this.href }),
        jQuery("<a>", { href: this.href }) 
    );
});
```

P.S - I already tried adding this code after the first function, but it wouldn't help either.

```
jQuery("#imageBox a").attr("target","_blank");
```

Here is the live link if it helps at all. Please forgive the website's poor coding. I first built it a couple years ago when I was rather inexperienced.

http://highlevelconstructionltd.com/river-ridge-estates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to define the `target` when you create the element:

```
jQuery(".gallery-item a").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    jQuery("#imageBox").append(
        jQuery("<img>", { src: this.href }),
        jQuery("<a>", { href: this.href, target: '_blank' }) // <-- Define the target
    );
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is exactly what I needed. I tried doing something similar initially, but I believe I put quotes around the 'target:', which I see now was wrong. Thanks so much !

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
jQuery("#imageBox a").attr("target","_blank");
```

With

```
jQuery("#imageBox a").prop("target","_blank");
```

This should work. See the demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4PkJq/5/).

Comment: Thanks Rajesh ! I ended up taking sbeliv01's route, but this will be good to know for future reference. Cheers !